# How to start working on async task in one activity and inform another activity on completion of work in OnBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to achieve the following behaviour, but I'm not sure how:

```
   1. User start an activity
   2. Activity starts an AsyncTask
   3. After initiating the AsyncTask,the control is transferred to another activity.
   4. Now,when the AsynTask finishes its work,the 2nd activity should get to know that        AsyncTask has completed its working in the previous activity.
```

I don't know how to achieve that functionality.`I know how to use AsyncTask` but i don't know how to inform any activity other than its parent activity about the finishing of its work.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

I want to do it because in 1st activity i want to start some working  in AsyncTask,then the control is transferred to 2nd activity but the AsyncTask is still running.When the AsyncTask will complete its functionality,i want to inform the 2nd activity about it and then want to perform some function in the 2nd activity.

Comment: Your design sounds suspicious.  Please edit your post and explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: Like Simon said you have to explain your design

Comment: Please check the edit.Shall i explain it more or it is understood now?

Comment: What for 1st activity? just for run Async task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create BroadcastReceiver in second activity and register it using
  registerReceiver() method.
- sendBroadcast() in AsyncTask    onPostExecute() method of first
  Activity.

  ```
  public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
      private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver =
          new BroadcastReceiver() {
              @Override
              public void onReceive(...) {
                  ...
              }
         });

      ...

      public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();  
                      filter.addAction("com.example.asynctaskcompleted");  
                      filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
          registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);
      }

      public void onPause() {
          super.onPause();
          ...
          unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
      }
      ...
  }


  public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
      private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
          ...
      }    

      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          Intent intent = new Intent ("com.example.asynctaskcompleted");            

          FirstActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
   }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2):

You can create `interface`, pass it to the `AsyncTask` (in constructor), and then call interface method in `onPostExecute`..and make your second activity implements this interface..

For example:

Your interface:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted();
}
```

Your second Activity:

```
public MyActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {
    //your Activity
}
```

And your AsyncTask:

```
public YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object> { //change Object to required type
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;

    public YourTask(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    //required methods

    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        //your stuff
        listener.onTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir,i am not understanding how you are informing the 2nd activity about the completion of AsyncTask in the 1st one.

Comment: here i'm informing the 2nd activity about the completion of AsyncTask from onPostExecute of the AsyncTask, not from the 1st activity..