# Getting a grip on a lost AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

Here's the scenario I'm struggling with:
The user starts my app and presses the Download button. The app starts a download on its own (with an AsyncTask, not using the System DownloadManager) and shows progress in the notifications. Now the user presses the back button, which finishes the activity. Except the AsyncTask and notification keep going, even with their "parent" activity finished.
Now the user goes back into the app by clicking on the notification. Because the last activity was finished and onDestroy() was called, a new activity gets created. The problem is this new activity has no idea that an AsyncTask from a previous instance of itself is still going, and so it shows the Download button again. Clicking this creates a duplicate AsyncTask and notification. Not good.

How can the new activity get a handle on this "lost" AsyncTask so that it can get information from it?

Ideas I'm **not** looking for:

- Blocking/overwriting onBackPressed
- Constantly sending info through SharedPreferences

Comment: Why not use a `BroadcastReceiver` to inform the other activity? Like, when your `asyncTask` "completes" in whatever state you can issue a callback in second activity. An old thread is there, you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718827/3991696

Comment: instead of finishing activity, you can implement moveTasktoBack(TRUE) inside onBackPressed, which will move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack.Now when you backpresss and come back, onResume will be called,so no recreation

Comment: @VishwarajAnand I set up a metric tonne of local broadcasts (constant progress updates from the AsyncTask are necessary) and it works! Thanks for the idea.